# Is there a more terse way to accomplish this?

Tags: java

Is there a more terse way to accomplish this?

```
private boolean fieldLockExists(String tableName, String fieldName, Integer id)
{
  List<MpFieldLocks> fieldLocks = getFieldLocks(tableName, id);
  boolean exists = false;

  for (MpFieldLocks fieldLock: fieldLocks)
  {
    if (Objects.equals(fieldLock.getFieldName(), fieldName))
    {
      exists = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  return exists;
}
```

I know I could return from within the for loop to make it shorter. I'm looking for a more fundamental change, if possible.

In C# I might use LINQ. In Java, I'm not sure.

Comment: Why don't you just return in the `if` statement? That way you don't need the break or the `exists` variable, for starters...

Comment: Use any library/API that has an `any` function.

Comment: I know I could return from within the for loop to make it shorter. I'm looking for a more fundamental change, if possible.

Comment: @mattalxndr: Well it *is* possible if you're using Java 8 - as per my answer - but if you're going to ask for a terser version of code when there's a pretty obvious way of making it a bit terser (and more readable, IMO) then it's worth doing that *before* asking.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Java 8, you can use streams:

```
private boolean fieldLockExists(String tableName, String fieldName, Integer id)
{
    return getFieldLocks(tableName, id)
        .stream()
        .anyMatch(fl -> Objects.equals(fl.getFieldName(), fieldName));
}
```

Comment: Yours is shorter and could be parallelized.  Good work.

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean fieldLockExists(String tableName, String fieldName, Integer id)
{
  return getFieldLocks(tableName, id).stream().
                  filter(s->s.equals(fieldName)).
                  findfirst().isPresent();
}
```